# How to import Excel files which are in protected view because of being downloaded from the Internet

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to manipulate through R a large list of Excel files that have been downloaded from the internet. However, as such, they are in protected view mode and both readxl and openxlsx can't read them properly. If I open the file manually and enable editing, then the importers work fine.

The problem is that opening every file to enable them would be very time-consuming. I have tried [changing Office 365 settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bm5) to stop protected view from happening. However, I have seen that then protected view disappears automatically when opening manually the file, saving it and closing it, but not before.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are other packages that might do the job (can not test it on your file) readxl or xlsx or XLConnect

Comment: you can use e.g. powershell to unblock them (if you are sure the files are safe): look [here](https://superuser.com/q/38476) - although the thread is pretty old - I think you will find a method that could help you - or [here](https://www.404techsupport.com/2016/06/24/unblock-files-powershell/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Power Query to load all the file. This would be an option to load multiple files without opening each one of them.